# How can I walk an array and split each element apart?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array like this in PHP:

```
array('aaa_BC98E90D8ADA0',
      'aab_KD9098DF90F',

      ...

      'd5d_KDO90290393',
      'nnn_OPDOE82993KD',
       'kbh_Doodie0DDK',
       ...
     );
```

How can I split each entry around the "_" and take the right hand token and assign each to a unique variable?

```
$aaa = 'BC98E90D8ADA0';

$aab = 'KD9098DF90F';

...

$d5d = 'KDO90290393';

$nnn = 'OPDOE82993KD';

$kbh = 'Doodie0DDK';

...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_to_split = array(
    'aaa_BC98E90D8ADA0',
    'aab_KD9098DF90F',
    'd5d_KDO90290393',
    'nnn_OPDOE82993KD',
    'kbh_Doodie0DDK',
 );

foreach($array_to_split as $val) {
    $var = explode($val);
    $$var[0] = $var[1];
}
```

That should dynamically set the var name as well as its key however i would prefer to do it this way.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array_to_split as $val) {
    $new_array[] = explode('_', $val);
}

echo $new_array['aaa']; // output, BC98E90D8ADA0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$array_to_split = array(
    'aaa_BC98E90D8ADA0',
    'aab_KD9098DF90F',
    'd5d_KDO90290393',
    'nnn_OPDOE82993KD',
    'kbh_Doodie0DDK',
);
foreach ($array_to_split as $value) {
    $temp = explode('_', $value);
    if(count($temp)==2){
        list($key,$val) = $temp;
        $$key = $val;
    }
}
echo $aaa;  //BC98E90D8ADA0
?>
```